# I need a fresh pair of eyes for this Game

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.4

I've been trying to create a Rock-Paper-Scissor game [ Sort of ;-) ], But for some reason when the Computer wins it doesn't display it, it gives me an error. Could someone read through the code and tell me what could be the problem. 
(I am very new to coding, and there are probably a million mistakes so please explain them clearly )

```
import random

class Game:

    def __init__(self, human):
        # These are the possible hands and their corresponding numbers
        self.hand = {

            1: "Rock", 2: "Paper", 3: "Scissors",
            4: "Lizard", 5: "Spock", 6: "Spider-Man",
            7: "Batman", 8: "Wizard", 9: "Gun"
        }

        #  Here we write the "Hand" and "What it beats + Wining Message"
        self.message = {

            "Rock": {"Scissors": "Rock crushes Scissors",
                     "Lizard": "Rock crushes Lizard.",
                     "Spider-Man": "Rock knocks out Spider-Man.",
                     "Wizard": "Rock interrupts Wizard."},

            "Paper": {"Rock": "Paper covers Rock.",
                      "Spock": "Paper disproves Spock.",
                      "Batman": "Paper delays Batman.",
                      "Gun": "Paper jams Gun."},

            "Scissors": {"Paper": "Scissors cut Paper.",
                         "Lizard": "Scissors decapitates Lizard.",
                         "Spider-Man": "Scissors cut Spider-Man.",
                         "Wizard": "Scissors cut Wizard."},

            "Lizard": {"Paper": "Lizard eats Paper.",
                       "Spock": "Lizard poisons Spock.",
                       "Batman": "Lizard confuses Batman, because he looks like Killer Croc.",
                       "Gun": "Lizard is too small for the Gun."},

            "Spock": {"Rock": "Spock vaporizes Rock.",
                      "Scissors": "Spock smashes Scissors.",
                      "Spider-Man": "Spock befuddles Spider-Man.",
                      "Wizard": "Spock zaps Wizard."},

            "Spider-Man": {"Paper": "Spider-Man rips paper.", "Lizard": "Spider-Man defeats Lizard.",
                           "Wizard": "Spider-Man annoys Wizard.", "Gun": "Spider-Man disarms the Gun."},

            "Batman": {"Rock": "Batman explodes Rock.", "Scissors": "Batman dismantles Scissors",
                       "Spock": "Batman hangs Spock.", "Spider-Man": "Batman scares Spider-Man."},

            "Wizard": {"Paper": "Wizard burns Paper.", "Lizard": "Wizard transforms Lizard.",
                       "Batman": "Wizard stuns Batman.", "Gun": "Wizard melts the Gun."},

            "Gun": {"Rock": "Gun breaks Rock.", "Scissors": "Gun dents Scissors.",
                    "Spock": "Gun shoots Spock.", "Batman": "Gun kills Batman's mom."}

        }

        # human selection and computer selection
        self.human = human
        self.computer = random.randint(1, len(self.hand))

    #  This function selects a winner, depending of beating hands
    # The winner is picked by assuming the human is the default winner
    # 'else' the computer wins.
    def show_hand(self):
        print(("You played ", self.hand[self.human], " the computer played ", self.hand[self.computer], "!"))


    def beats(self):
        if self.hand[self.human] == self.hand[self.computer]:
            return "It's a tie!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Rock":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Scissors" or "Lizard" or "Spider-Man" or "Wizard":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Paper":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Rock" or "Spock" or "Batman" or "Gun":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Scissors":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Paper" or "Lizard" or "Spider-Man" or "Wizard":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Lizard":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Paper" or "Spock" or "Batman" or "Gun":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Spock":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Rock" or "Scissors" or "Spider-Man" or "Wizard":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Spider-Man":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Paper" or "Lizard" or "Wizard" or "Gun":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Batman":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Rock" or "Scissors" or "Spock" or "Spider-Man":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Wizard":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Paper" or "Lizard" or "Batman" or "Gun":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"

        elif self.hand[self.human] == "Gun":
            if self.hand[self.computer] == "Rock" or "Scissors" or "Spock" or "Batman":
                return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
            else:
                return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"


def main():
    while True:
        intro()
        while True:
            instructions()
            while True:
                print()
                player_input = input("Please make your selection: ")
                print()

                if int(player_input) == 1 or player_input.lower() == "rock":
                    player_input = 1
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 2 or player_input.lower() == "paper":
                    player_input = 2
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 3 or player_input.lower() == "scissors":
                    player_input = 3
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 4 or player_input.lower() == "lizard":
                    player_input = 4
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 5 or player_input.lower() == "spock":
                    player_input = 5
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 6 or player_input.lower() == "spider-man" or player_input.lower() == \
                        "spiderman":
                    player_input = 6
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 7 or player_input.lower() == "batman":
                    player_input = 7
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 8 or player_input.lower() == "wizard":
                    player_input = 8
                    break
                elif int(player_input) == 9 or player_input.lower() == "gun":
                    player_input = 9
                    break
                else:
                    print("There seems to be an error on your selection."),
                    print("Please read the instructions well and try again.")
                    print()

                    instructions()

            game = Game(player_input)

            print()
            game.show_hand()
            print()

            print(game.beats())

            if game.beats() == "It's a tie!":
                print()
                print("Give it one more try!")
                print()
            else:
                break

            cont = input("Do you want to play again (Y/N)?\n\n: ")
            if cont.lower() == "no" or "n":
                break


def intro():
    print()
    print("This is a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock,\nSpider-Man, Batman, Wizard, Gun.")
    print("You will be playing vs the Computer.")
    print()


def instructions():
    print()
    print("*Instructions*")
    print()
    print('Enter "1" or "Rock" for Rock')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "2" or "Paper" for Paper')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "3" or "Scissors" for Scissors')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "4" or "Lizard" for Lizard')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "5" or "Spock" for Spock')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "6" or "Spider-Man" for Spider-Man')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "7" or "Batman" for Batman')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "8" or "Wizard" for Wizard')
    print('or')
    print('Enter "9" or "Gun" for Gun')
    print()

main()
```

I don't think StackOverflow got my indentation correctly. If you want the original file, here it's. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxbNlq7y4nLxMHp2WVF5OUNqd3M

Comment: Post the error message pls!

Comment: `Please make your selection: 1


('You played ', 'Rock', ' the computer played ', 'Paper', '!')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Documents/PycharmProjects/User/Rock Paper Scissors V2.0.py", line 221, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/User/Documents/PycharmProjects/User/Rock Paper Scissors V2.0.py", line 177, in main
    print(game.beats())
  File "/Users/User/Documents/PycharmProjects/User/Rock Paper Scissors V2.0.py", line 73, in beats
    return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
KeyError: 'Paper'`

Comment: Seriously? What's the deal with comments #1 and  #2? Could the posters (or anyone entitled to do so) remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KeyError` you are getting indicates you are trying to access a key that doesn't exist in the dictionary. Looking over your code, it seems that your `self.messages` dictionary doesn't contain 'Paper' as a key in *all* of the sub-dictionaries.

Now, lets take a look and try to improve this code. First off, the print call doesn't need to be so confusing.

```
def show_hand(self):
    print(("You played ", self.hand[self.human], " the computer played ", self.hand[self.computer], "!"))
```

can be

```
def show_hand(self, human, computer):
    print("You played {}, the computer played {}!".format(human, computer))
```

Now, just pass in the variables to that method call.

Further, lets address the beats method. We can use the same process, pass in self.human and self.computer. That cuts out a lot of extra noise in the code:

```
def beats(self, human, computer):
    if human == computer:
        return "It's a tie!"
```

Now, lets address the user input sanitization. It could be a ton easier! You can reasonably expect either a string (indicating the user entered something like `paper`) or an integer. So why not validate the input once you pass it into the game?

```
def __init__(self, human):
    ...
    if human.isdigit():
        self.human = int(human)
    else:
        reversed = {v.lower(): k for k, v in self.hand.iteritems()}
        self.human = reversed.get(human.lower())
        if not self.human:
            raise Exception("Not a valid choice")
```

Boom, done.

Comment: that won't work, because `.format(human,computer)` can't pass computer is a `self.computer` variable and `.format()` won't accept it, I've tried it allready.

Comment: I can assure you that you can pass instance variables into class methods. Like this: `self.show_hand(self.human, self.computer)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong, it wanted me to wrinte the `if` statement like this

```
    `if self.hand[self.computer] == "Rock" or self.hand[self.computer] == "Scissors" or self.hand[self.computer] == "Spider-Man" or self.hand[self.computer] == "Wizard":
            return self.message[self.hand[self.human]][self.hand[self.computer]] + " You Win!"
        else:
            return self.message[self.hand[self.computer]][self.hand[self.human]] + " The Computer Wins!"`
```

I thought jurt placing `or` between the conditions would be enough.